# Git, you branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits. What to do?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
```

Hi, as you can see the message is obvious.

I don't want to screw up with this by doing weird stuff.

Unfortunately, I made some changes and then commits from my master branch without checkin out a new branch.

Now, every time I need to pull the new code git tries to merge my branch with the origin ( source of the project ).
As a result, every time I try to pull my current branch ends up with being ahead of 'origin/master' by N+1 commits.

Its really annoying me. Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `pull --rebase`.

Comment: What do *you* want to do?

Comment: I just want to have my master back in order to pull data without weird messages. I am happy to drop the commits since they're not important.

Comment: @choroba I tried the command you suggested ( git pull --rebase ). It worked well but my master is still ahead by 1 commit. Do you know how to solve it ? Thanks in advance  !

Comment: You can now push the 1 commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new branch now:

```
# create new branch based upon current state   
git checkout -b <new branch>

# delete the master with the "extra" commits
git branch -D master

# update your local repo
git fetch --all --prune

# checkout the master tot get the latest code 
# while your changes are left in your new branch
git checkout master
```

Comment: What happens if I just run "git reset --hard 'origin/master' " ?

Comment: You will simply lose all your local uncomimted changes